# If anyone is currently logged in don't open login or signup page

Tags: c#, asp.net

If user is already logged-in and he/she is trying to open `Login.aspx` page then he must redirect to the homepage of the website and if user is logged-out or the session has timed out then the user could be able to redirect to Homepage.

I am trying this piece of code.

```
if (Session["username"] != null)
{
   Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");
}
```

Comment: "I am trying this kind of code" and I wish you good luck with that! :)

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: I want to do something like facebook or youtube does. If someone is currently logged in they don't allow to open login page instead they redirect them to their respective home page. That's what I am trying to do

Comment: @Aars93 good luck to you too. If you find some solution later please mention it hear

Comment: @Johndope Don't worry , From your question I understand that you want to achieve a functionality that when user is trying to visit "Login.aspx" , If user is already login then he/she must be redirected to the Homepage of your website, 
you just have to add your code to your login page form load method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to write this piece of code in your Page_Load method in "Login.aspx.cs" file. [image]

your code with method will be like this

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (Session["username"] != null) // Checks if username is available in session
   {
       Response.Redirect("Homepage.aspx");  // If user is logged in than redirect to Homepage.aspx 
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for reply. I tried this code too but login.aspx still opens up.

Comment: you are using 
   Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");
instead of 
Response.Redirect("Homepage.aspx");

Try it

Comment: @Johndope, Did you add value in Session on Login???? If you are trying to achieve all functionality by only this code then you are doing it wrong, You must have to add value to Session when user login, then this this piece of code works

Comment: Yeah, I 'll happy to help. Please share your login page code, so i'll tell you where you did wrong. :)

Comment: protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Session["username"] != null) // Checks if username is available in session
        {
            Response.Redirect("Dashboard.aspx");  // If user is logged in than redirect to Homepage.aspx 
        }

Comment: I am asking about the code, Where user write username/password, where is the authentication code???

Comment: I have found a solution for you, kindly learn from this tutorial , How you can login in asp.net webform.
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/009464/how-to-make-a-login-form-using-session-in-Asp-Net-C-Sharp/